# How many file descriptors are closed when I call close on a socket file descriptor?

Tags: posix, file-descriptor

Just as the title says: how many file descriptors are closed when I call close on a socket file descriptor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One.
It should just be the one identified by the argument you pass to close(2).

Comment: I thought the same, but this is a practice question given to me, so I'm just trying to figure out if there's a trick here.

Comment: I was intrigued by the question too.